# Families of arithmetic fields arising from arithmetic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose we have a polynomial $f(x,y)$ in two variables over a number field $k$, e.g., $y^2 - x^3 + x +1$. As we put different $k$-values of $y$ in the polynomial and adjoin the roots of the resulting polynomial in $x$ to $k$, we get different field extensions of $k$. We can think of this as a one-parameter algebraic family of number fields generated by $f$ over $k$, and ask how the structures and invariants associated with this family vary. For example, we can take normal closures and ask how their Galois groups vary, or how their zeta functions behave, or even the associated "reciprocity laws". We'd expect that the variation is related to the geometry of the curve $C: f(x,y) = 0$.

We can, of course, get another family from specializing $x$ instead of $y$, and there would be other ways of fibering $C$ over $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ to get other families of number fields as well. The collection, $\mathcal{F}(C, k)$, of all such (isomorphism classes of) families of number fields arising from a single curve $C$ may itself have an interesting structure and a relationship to $C$ over $k$ worth looking at. (Is $\mathcal{F}$ a representable functor?)

We can carry out this process for any $n$-dimensional variety $V$ over an arbitrary field $k$, i.e., specialize to $k$ in all but one dimensions, and thereby, get an $(n-1)$ -parameter family of field extensions of $k$, and then ask how the properties of the family, and of the family of such families are determined by the geometry of $V$, but I am interested in the arithmetic setting, primarily when $k$ is a number field, but also when it is a finite field or $p$-adic field, and curves are enough to begin with. The case of elliptic curves would be specially interesting where the group structure and modularity can play significant roles.

General study of these of families of arithmetic fields arising from varieties over arithmetic fields must be well-known. Where can one begin to learn about this theory and its implications?

Comment: This is essentially covered by "Hilbert's Irreducibility Theorem". Serres Topics in Galois Theory is a good reference for this.

Comment: Some invariants of the field will emerge from Hilbert Irreducibility as mentioned above. On the other hand, even if you take a simple equation like $y^2-x$, you cannot expect, for different values of $x$, too much relation between the class numbers of the corresponding fields (which are all quadratic fields!).

Comment: BTW: Your use of the term "arithmetic variety" is non-standard and should be avoided.